# Find value of $\cot^620^\circ-9\cot^420^\circ+11\cot^220^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

What I've tried is factoring out $\cot^220^\circ$

$$\cot^220^\circ(\cot^420^\circ-9\cot^220^\circ+11)$$

but this quadratic can't be factor with integers so I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $$\cot3x=\dfrac{3c-c^3}{1-3c^2}$$

where $c=\cot x$

Set $3x=60^\circ$

$$\implies\sqrt3(3c-c^3)=1-3c^2$$

Take square in both sides and simplify

Observe that the relationship will hold true for $$3x=180^\circ n+60^\circ\iff x=60^\circ n+20^\circ$$ where $n$ is any integer